# New OpenRefine install produces almost blank landing page (no menus)

Tags: openrefine

```
OS: Windows 10 Pro 64 bit 19042.985
JDK: OpenJDK 16.0.1+9-24
OpenRefine: openrefine-3.4.1
Browser: Firefox 88.0.1
```

Just installed OpenRefine for the first time, on top of a fresh install of OpenJDK 16

The server runs and opens the URL (localhost:3333) in the browser, but the page that comes up is almost blank. There is the OpenRefine logo in the top left corner, but the rest of the page is empty. There is no UI (menus).

--UPDATE--

Looking at the page html in more detail it's not strictly true that there is no content in the menus. There are a small number of links in [li] tags, but these are being rendered as 0-width elements by the browser (in either Firefox or Edge) so they are no visible on the page.

By the looks of it the page is failing to load several external references including the stylesheets, and I suspect that's linked to the bad rendering of the page.

--END UPDATE--

The OpenRefine log output is-

```
12:39:39.088 [            refine_server] Starting Server bound to '127.0.0.1:3333' (0ms)
12:39:39.088 [            refine_server] Initializing context: '/' from 'C:\OpenRefine\openrefine-3.4.1\webapp' (0ms)
12:39:39.458 [            refine_server] Failed to use jdatapath to detect user data path: resorting to environment variables (370ms)
12:39:39.458 [            refine_server] Failed to use jdatapath to detect user data path: resorting to environment variables (0ms)
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/OpenRefine/openrefine-3.4.1/server/target/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.18.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/OpenRefine/openrefine-3.4.1/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.18.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
12:39:39.573 [                   refine] Starting OpenRefine 3.4.1 [437dc4d]... (115ms)
12:39:39.573 [                   refine] initializing FileProjectManager with dir (0ms)
12:39:39.573 [                   refine] C:\Users\coev\AppData\Roaming\OpenRefine (0ms)
12:39:39.573 [       FileProjectManager] Failed to load workspace from any attempted alternatives. (0ms)
12:39:43.367 [          org.mortbay.log] /images/favicon.png (3794ms)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Committed
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Response.resetBuffer(Response.java:1024)
        at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.resetBuffer(ServletResponseWrapper.java:202)
        at org.mortbay.servlet.GzipFilter$GZIPResponseWrapper.resetBuffer(GzipFilter.java:310)
        at org.mortbay.servlet.GzipFilter$GZIPResponseWrapper.sendError(GzipFilter.java:319)
        at edu.mit.simile.butterfly.Butterfly.error(Butterfly.java:1020)
        at edu.mit.simile.butterfly.Butterfly.service(Butterfly.java:528)
        at com.google.refine.RefineServlet.service(RefineServlet.java:210)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
        at org.mortbay.servlet.UserAgentFilter.doFilter(UserAgentFilter.java:81)
        at org.mortbay.servlet.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:132)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector$Connection.run(SocketConnector.java:228)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
```

I originally installed OpenRefine in `C:\Program Files\OpenRefine\openrefine-3.4.1` but thinking this might one of those Unix-native apps that can't handle pathnames with spaces this log is from a second install in `C:\OpenRefine\openrefine-3.4.1`.

When OpenRefine runs, with the first install (in `Program Files`) just a blank workspace was created in `C:\Users\coev\AppData\Roaming\OpenRefine`. With the second install directly in C: it gets as far as creating a `workspace.json` file in that folder, so that's one difference.

Looking at the html page source generated by OpenRefine the html looks valid, but the  blocks for the left and right menu panels are empty.

I have searched but haven't found this specific issue decribed elsewhere. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you create a bug in Github https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/issues/new/choose or contact the project support mailing list: https://groups.google.com/group/openrefine

Comment: Bug created on GitHub, BugID  #3913.

Although it's not obvious from the bug title, looking at the details I think BugID #3869 is describing the same issue, which may be centred on the JS error "Refine is not defined"

Comment: Looking at the bug history on OpenRefine it appears this might be a compatibility issue with Java 16. Hopefully at some point one of the developers will confirm that on GitHub.